# What takes precedence: buildpack stack version or heroku settings version?

Tags: heroku, stack, buildpack

I was updating the stack version from one of the apps I maintain from `Cedar-14` to the `Heroku-18`.

This app builds on a custom buildpack, so I updated the stack version on the buildpack code, but the build still failed **until** the stack version was updated on the app's settings through Heroku's dashboard.

This leads me to believe that the config on the UI takes precedence over the buildpack config, but I couldn't find any documentation to corroborate my findings.

Could anyone tell me if there's any documentation on which configuration takes precedence the builpack or the settings one?

`Edit:` I have two apps running on said builpack, the first one I updated the stack version through the UI and the buildpack code simultaneously, and the build didn't fail. The second one, the reason for opening this question, I only updated the stack version on the builpack, the build failed, then I updated the stack version on the UI, causing the build to succeed.

The buildpack can be found [here](https://github.com/pyladies-brazil/heroku-buildpack-pelican) and the log from the app that errored can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jtemporal/62e8e12316600e679e0c84601246395c).

Comment: buildpacks don't set the stack, they only use the value in `$STACK`. can you elaborate on what you mean by "buildpack config"?

Comment: @codefinger by "buildpack config" I meant the buildpack that can be found [here](https://github.com/pyladies-brazil/heroku-buildpack-pelican). And good to know that buildpacks do set the stack... Now it makes sense why the build broke when the stack version wasn't updated on the second app.